# Visual Studio 2019 (16.2.1) no longer has checkbox to support .net core prerelease versions

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio v16.2.1, there is no button to include .net core versions in pre-release any more. After upgrading to this version, I am unable to build .net core 3 preview 7 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [.Net Core 3.0 (Preview) use Visual Studio 16.3 (currently Preview channel with Preview 2)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-8/), this is first version that fully supports .Net Core 3.0 and .Net core 3.0 will ship the same time like VS2019 16.3 final.

> **NET Core 3.0 Preview**
>   .NET Core 3.0 Preview 8 requires Visual Studio 2019 16.3 Preview 2 or
>   later