# Can't find the option for .Net Core 3 in VS 2019

Tags: .net-core, ide, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I've installed the latest .Net Core 3 SDK, and my VS 2019 *(Community)* is up to date 4.7.0.0362.

I wanted to utilise .Net Core 3's new 'single exe' publish option, so .Net Core 2.2 doesn't do what I need, but 2.2 is the latest framework I have the option to use when creating a new project. VS2019 doesn't seem to recognise that .Net Core 3 is installed.

### What I've Tried

Tools > Options > Preview - and I have checked the box that would allow me to use preview versions of the framework.

I've also tried multiple reboots.

I've also ran `dotnet --info` and `dotnet --version` to check that .Net Core 3 was in fact on my machine.

### UPDATE

I can't see .Net Core 3 when creating a new project, but if I create a .Net Core 2.2 ASP .Net Core project I can then (via project properties) change it to target .Net Core 3.0. Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: [Here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral) the download link. Maybe you installed x86 version and you have VS x64? Or the other way around...

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoIsidori - but I have installed both (even though my system is x64) but still not showing.

Comment: The option to create projects based on .net core 3.0 is there in the vs19 preview edition. It is also strongly recommended to use .net core 3.0 along side the vs19 preview as seen on it's [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)

Comment: It's not there in my edition though!? I do have the latest VS 2019 update I believe.

Comment: Please note that [visual studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/), is not [visual studio 2019 preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)

Comment: Thanks @MXD! I will give this a go. If it works, post it as the answer. Will let you know.

Comment: you need to use VS2019 [16.3 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480145/1466046)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2019 does not detect .Net Core 3 pre-release 9 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835629/visual-studio-2019-does-not-detect-net-core-3-pre-release-9-sdk)