# Visual Studio 2019 does not detect .Net Core 3 pre-release 9 SDK

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I only have `.Net Core 3 pre-release 9` currently installed and if I want to create a new ASP.Net Core application it tells me the following.

[image]

I even turned on `Use previews of the .Net Core SDK` in the settings and ensured that `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` is at the very top of my PATH environment variable. Also I am using Visual Studio `Version 16.2.4`.

If I type `dotnet --info` it shows me the following:

[image]

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of VS2019 (16.2.4 as of this writing)?

Comment: @IanKemp Yes I have. At least the `About Visual Studio` page shows that.

Comment: I wonder why you would downvote this, but sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need VS2019 Preview, not RTM, installed and up-to-date to use .NET Core 3.0 previews with VS: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-9/

> .NET Core 3.0 is supported with Visual Studio 2019 16.3 Preview 3 and Visual Studio for Mac 8.3, which were also released today. Please upgrade to it for the best (and supported) experience with .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9. See Visual Studio 2019 16.3 release notes for more information.
>
> We know that some folks have been successful using .NET Core 3.0 builds with Visual Studio 2019 16.2 and wonder why 16.3 is required. The short answer is that we only test .NET Core 3.0 with Visual Studio 2019 16.3 and have made many improvements and key fixes that are only in 16.3.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot, I will try it and accept it as the answer as soon as I can verify it working.