# WPF template not working with .NET Core 3 Preview 8 3.0.100.13656 and VS 2019 16.2.3

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core

Regardless of whether I have .NET Core 3 Preview 8 x64 or x86 SDK only, or both x64 and x86 Preview 8 SDKs installed I always get this error message in VS 2019 16.2.3:

[image]

This option is, of course, checked in the settings:

[image]

When I check the version in the Package Manager Console this is displayed:

PM> dotnet --version

3.0.100-preview8-013656

Furthermore, when I attempt to create a new ASP.NET Core Web App I get:

[image]

C:ProgramFiles\dotnet is of course in the PATH and the Preview 8 x64 is installed there and the folder contains dotnet.exe file.

[image]

I uninstalled all the 2.x versions of the SDK while experimenting with this but I was getting the same error when I had 3 different 2.x versions installed.

Any ideas what is going on here and how to get this template to work with .NET Core Preview 8?

Interestingly enough I was able to create a new solution and add both of these projects manually from the Console by issuing following commands:

```
dotnet new sln
dotnet new wpf
dotnet new webapi
dotnet sln add path/wpf.csproj
dotnet sln add path/webapi.csproj
```

Comment: Did you try the vs 16.3 preview? .net core 3.0 is meant to be used with that only

Comment: you need to use [VS2019 16.3 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480145/1466046)

Comment: You mean the templates are designed to work with 16.3 only? Because I was able to create everything manually...

Comment: Microsoft tests .net core 3.0 only against 16.3 and only supports this VS versions. 3.0 and 16.3 ship the same time in September 2019

Comment: @magicandre1981 Gotcha, post it as answer and I'll accept it...

Comment: upvote the original answer that I linked so that I can vote to close it as duplicate. There is not need to post the same information in several answers .

Comment: @magicandre1981 That is not the same question and the answer is incorrect because you can create and build .NET Core 3 WPF apps with 16.2...

Comment: it may work or not in 16.2. Microsoft only supports .net core 3 with 16.3. I'm out here of this topic, I already answered it.